# How do I turn off JScript Intellisense in vs2008?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2008

When working in VS2008 in a large aspx file the program grinds to halt updating JScript intellisense.

Is their a way to turn this off?

It's not listed in Tools>Options>Text Editor. Already have the AllLanguages.AutoListMembers and AllLanguages.ParameterInformation turned off.

EDIT:
VS2008 did not have sp1 installed. As to why it doesn't have SP1 I don't know. Not listed in my Microsoft Updates. Forcing a manual install right now. AARRGGGHHHHHHH!!!!!!1!

EDIT 2:
An hour and a half later and the SP1 is installed and updated. BTW these are the macros i use to turn off and on the intellisense:

```
Sub Intellisense_Off()
    Dim textEditor As Properties
    textEditor = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "AllLanguages")
    textEditor.Item("AutoListMembers").Value = False
    textEditor.Item("AutoListParams").Value = False
End Sub

Sub Intellisense_On()
    Dim textEditor As Properties
    textEditor = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "AllLanguages")
    textEditor.Item("AutoListMembers").Value = True
    textEditor.Item("AutoListParams").Value = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tools>Options>TextEditor>JScript

You can turn it off there.

Comment: Don't have that as an option. 
Only have the following languages listed: 
All Languages, Basic, C#, C/C++, CSS, HTML, PL/SQL, Plain Text, SQL Script, T-SQL, T-SQL7, T-SQL80, T-SQL90, XAML, XML, XOML

Comment: That's crazy, I have everything you mentioned AND JScript...

Which version of VS2k8?

Comment: You may not have Visual Studio Service Pack 1. That's where they officially added all of the JScript stuff, including the option I mentioned.

Comment: VS2008 Version 9.021022.8 RTM.... doh no service pack 1. looks like that feature wasn't added till then.

Comment: send more details , which options to turn off, I tried them but when I compile project at last I get the following message : "error updating JScript intellisense see error list."